# Android studio send info to other activity in the background

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

Let's say I have two activities called screen1 and screen 2 and there is a textview on screen2.

How can I update the tesxt on screen2 using a variable on screen1 but make it so that the user is not redirected to screen2?

If I use intent to putextra on screen1 and then getintent on screen2, the screen that the user sees changes in this process but I want the app showing screen1 the entire time.

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: There's really no point in updating the Views in the second Activity until it's displayed.

Comment: Only one `Activity` can be visible at a time.